# mysql Select from where sum of columns is less than

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select from a database table like the folowing...

```
id   | task         | last_run    | interval
 1   |  test-run    |  1369715091 |  30
 2   |  anothertask |  1369715091 |  60
```

`last_run` is unix-time, updated by the script, when it runs.
Interval is the time between runs when this task needs to be executed.

What I need to do is run a query where I select only the tasks where `last_run`+`interval` is less than the current time.

This is what I've come up with...

```
SELECT *, (`last_run`+`interval`) as next_run FROM `tasks` WHERE (`next_run` > '1369717906')
```

...however I get the error...

```
Unknown column 'next_run' in 'where clause'
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: This query worked. Thanks guys - can't accept an answer for 7 minutes..


SELECT *, (`last_run`+`interval`) as next_run FROM `cron` WHERE (`last_run`+`interval` < '1369719025')

Comment: TRy like this,Select * from tasks where ((last_run+interval)< curtime())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide those two names there instead of Alias

```
SELECT *, (`last_run`+`interval`) as next_run FROM `tasks` WHERE (`last_run`+`interval`)  > 1369717906
```

You cannot use Alias in a `WHERE` clause according to [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/problems-with-alias.html)

> An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses to refer to the column. Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined

Answer (score 1):

Use `(last_run+interval)` instead of `next_run` in your query.

Answer (score 1):

In the where clause, use the expression rather than the alias:

```
WHERE last_run + interval > 1369717906
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as  i know `where` clause cant use alias

so you have two options

either repeat the expression in where clause

```
SELECT *, (`last_run`+`interval`) as next_run FROM `tasks` WHERE (`last_run`+`interval`) > '1369717906'
```

Or use `having` which can use alias

```
SELECT *, (`last_run`+`interval`) as next_run FROM `tasks` HAVING (`next_run` > '1369717906')
```

see [MySQL Tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) and [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc8df/2)